# making a div and span fixed inside a grid layout

Tags: html, css

i tried to create a grid layout and faced this problem. I want to make the div (profile image) and span fixed inside the div (wrapper-profile-intro). My work is

```css
#main-profile{
    margin: 0;
    profile: 0;
}
.profile-container{
    max-width:1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper-profile{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "intro details details details";
    grid-gap: 0.5em;
}
.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-intro{
    grid-area: intro;
}
.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-details{
    grid-area: details;
}
.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-intro,.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-details{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.profile-header{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.profile-header img{
    display: cov0er;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.6;    
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.wrapper-profile-intro .profile-image{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items-center;
}
.wrapper-profile-intro .profile-image img{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow:1px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);  
  -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
  -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
}
.wrapper-profile-intro .profile-image span{
  position:absolute;
  background: #2afa6a;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  border-radius:50%;
  bottom:3px;
  left:11px;
  border:2px solid #fff;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .wrapper-profile{
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: "intro"
        "details";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="main-profile">
    <div class="profile-header">
        <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-grunge-decorative-relief-navy-blue-stucco-wall-texture-wide-angle-rough-colored-background_1258-28311.jpg?w=2000" alt="profile-header">
    </div>
    <div class="profile-container">
        <div class="wrapper-profile">
            <div class="wrapper-profile-intro">
                <div class="profile-image">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/01/12/58/icon-5359553_1280.png">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-profile-details">
                <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--profile-container-->
</div>
```

i tried position absolute and making relative the outside div , but it didn't work. See how can i make the div profile-image fix inside the div , wrapper-profile-intro.

Comment: What do you mean by fix? Fixed is a css property, I don't think you want that. In grid you can position element inside (self). But I'm afraid your grid construction is a bit complex for the design I've check

Comment: Yes design is bit complex. Fixed means position : absolute.

Comment: you want the image to stay on top of left, and right? what is it doing? scrolling? I think you have several profile container, each with image left and content right? My understanding is profile container has a certain height, image left on top, and scrolling right content, is it?

Comment: i want it to stay at absolute position of wrapper-profile-intro. See the code now.... i want in that position.

Comment: i want in that position as fixed or absolute , with respect to the div. Expand the snippet , you'll get to know where i require...but i want in that position to be fixed and also the span don't get out of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#main-profile{
    margin: 0;
    profile: 0;
}
.profile-container{
    max-width:1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper-profile{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "intro details details details";
}
.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-intro{
    grid-area: intro;
}
.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-details{
    grid-area: details;
}
.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-intro,.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-details{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 10px;
}
.profile-header{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.profile-header img{
    display: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.6;    
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.wrapper-profile-intro .profile-card{
    display:grid;
   }
.wrapper-profile-intro .profile-card .profile-image{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper-profile-intro .profile-image img{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow:1px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);  
  -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
  -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
}
.profile-card .profile-image span{
    position:absolute;
  display: flex;
  background: #2afa6a;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border:2px solid #fff;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .wrapper-profile{
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: "intro"
        "details";
    }
    .wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-intro,.wrapper-profile .wrapper-profile-details{
        margin-bottom: -5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="main-profile">
    <div class="profile-header">
        <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-grunge-decorative-relief-navy-blue-stucco-wall-texture-wide-angle-rough-colored-background_1258-28311.jpg?w=2000" alt="profile-header">
    </div>
    <div class="profile-container">
        <div class="wrapper-profile">
            <div class="wrapper-profile-intro">
                <div class="profile-card">
          <div class="profile-image">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/01/12/58/icon-5359553_1280.png">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-profile-details">
                <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--profile-container-->
</div>
```

this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

mmmm... I'm still not sure I perfectly understand what you are looking for... But I've done a snippet simpler than yours. Tell me if ok, and what to change in it.

For the @media working, don't forget to add in top of html

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main-profile {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.profile-header {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.profile-header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.wrapper-profile-container {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  justify-self: center;
  max-width: 1280px;
}

.profile-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper-profile-intro,
.wrapper-profile-details {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.wrapper-profile-intro {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper-profile-intro img {
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}

.wrapper-profile-intro span {
  position: absolute;
  background: #2afa6a;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .profile-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main-profile">
  <div class="profile-header">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-grunge-decorative-relief-navy-blue-stucco-wall-texture-wide-angle-rough-colored-background_1258-28311.jpg?w=2000" alt="profile-header">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-profile-container">
    <div class="profile-container">
      <div class="wrapper-profile-intro">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/01/12/58/icon-5359553_1280.png">
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-profile-details">
        <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-container">
      <div class="wrapper-profile-intro">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/01/12/58/icon-5359553_1280.png">
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper-profile-details">
        <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--profile-container-->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try to do my way i.e. By declaring grid area? it seems confusing for me....

Comment: https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/RwBoPbd ...try in this link.

Comment: the notation you are using "seems" clearer, it's not at all, and gives a very complex structure where it hasn't to be. You think you visualize because it's written in english but in fact, when problems, the complexity structure is hard to debug. I stopped using that. Direct positioning is lot easier.

Comment: Can anyone do??

Comment: check here https://cssgridbuilder.com/ (not yet finished) or other

Comment: didn't worked for me.